# How to export function from different package of go into static library so that I can call it from a cpp program

Tags: go

I have a *main package* and a *string package* in `go`.

In `main.go` (*main package*)I have one `//export function` and

In `string.go`(*string package*) I have another `//export function`.

When I run `"go build -buildmode=c-archive"` I see that the header file generated has only declaration of *main package* functions and it does not include any `//export functions` from *string package*.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, please tag only the one that is relevant to you and your project. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them (like showing us an [mre]).